# Is it possible for TFS2008 to build by labels

Tags: build, tfs, label

I have a question, is it possible for TFS2008 to be able to create a build by extracting files from a specific label? Lets say there are three labels within a branch and I would like to build only modified files from L2 to Latest so the build output drop folder only contains the items that were modified between L2 and Latest labels, is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm pretty sure you can't do that. Maybe you could build a custom build process template to do it or something.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into creating a custom process to do this.